# Flex line stroke is blurry, crooked or is not straight looking

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

**problem**: Line in flex using mxml that doesn't appear to be straight!?

```
<s:Line width="100%" height="2">
    <s:stroke>
        <s:SolidColorStroke color="0xbababa" />
    </s:stroke>
</s:Line>
```

Comment: This is great, thanks for sharing your find. Tip: You should form this as a question then move the solution to an answer and mark it as answered.  Otherwise it just looks like an unanswered question at first glance.

Comment: +1 to Wade's comment.  It is what I would consider proper etiquette on this site.

Comment: I went ahead and turned the question into a quetsion and posted the answer from the original question into an answer.  ( But, shi11i you should feel free to post your own answer as an answer, since the credit goes to you ).  If you do, I'll delete my own answer.

Comment: ahh awesome, makes sense! will do now. thnx Seth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution**: make sure to give the stroke a weight and remove the height property!

```
<s:Line top="20" xFrom="0" xTo="{this.width}">
<s:stroke>
<s:SolidColorStroke color="0xbababa" weight="1" />
</s:stroke>
</s:Line>
```

Comment: why is your answer an exact duplicate of flextras?

Comment: @grapefrukt Read the comments on the original question.  The @shi11i originally posted the question and answer as part of the question, as a service to others.  We recommended that he split it up into a question w/ a formal answer, and then mark his answer as correct.  I separated out the q&A to demonstrate the approach.

Comment: I went ahead and deleted my answer.  Be sure to mark your answer as the correct one.